# Setup central MySQL server for local environment

Tags: mysql, linux, web-development-server

We have a group of developers and designers, we want to create a single database server to use for everyone for better collaboration. We are running windows and Linux machines. So please give me suggestions how can i build this.

Comment: SO is about programming, not about how to set up a server. Even if this question were on-topic here, the way you asked it without any details, would mean that it is not specific enough.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can run MySQL on either of those types of machines. Go to the MySQL website and download an installer. Also download MySQLWorkbench to do setup after installation. You should be up in a very short time.

Comment: then how can i access it in my web apps ?

Comment: There are two steps. First point your apps at the ip address of the machine that you choose as a server. example; http://192.168.0.2/test/v1/appserver.php?request=getSomeData. Next you need to write some server side code and install it in the directory that your server uses for web services. In the example, "test" would be in that folder, "v1" inside that and the php file inside "v1".